# How to get a Particular field from an object array in a text file

Tags: php, arrays, api, file-get-contents

I am trying to get only the refresh_token field from the text file using file_get _contents. please anyone solve this.

```
{"access_token":"XXXX","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"XXXX"}
```

Comment: `echo $object->refresh_token`

Comment: tried that not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a json string

```
$content = file_get_contents([...]);
$arr = json_decode($content);

echo $arr->access_token;
```

Answer (score 2):

For json manipulation you should use `json_decode`

```
$str= file_get_contents(some.txt);
$array = json_decode($content);
echo $array->access_token;
```